# How to wait for upload to finish before submitting the form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery-file-upload

I have a form which submits via ajax (using Rails-ujs).

I also uses blueimp jquery-file-upload.

I want form submit to be halted by file uploads. If file upload is still on-going, form submit should wait until file-upload is finished first, then proceed.

Currently I just try to stop the submitting, but even that is not working:

```
  $('form').on('ajax:before', function() {
    if ($('.fileInput').fileupload('active') > 0) {
      return false
    }
  })
```

Comment: You think that form is submitted before the file is uploaded? But thing is this first file is uploaded then form is submitted;

Comment: The process is user can upload files first, multiple of them. And then user can click another form submission. I wish to not submit such form, not until all files have been uploaded.

Comment: You want to allow user to submit multiple file one by one then user can submit form then how you will manage the files uploaded before form submission?

Comment: I'll insert the file url as hidden inputs into the form. That's why I want it to all finish before the form gets submitted

Comment: Why don't use `$('form').on('submit'` ?

Comment: rails-ujs uses `ajax-before`, but it is similar things, and I think it is not too relevant to this question.

Answer (score 0):

If ajax:before callback is passed a form submit event, your code should be:

```
$('form').on('ajax:before', function(submitEvent) {
    if ($('.fileInput').fileupload('active') > 0) {
      submitEvent.preventDefault();
    }
})
```